# How to match dictionary value list items stored to items in a separate list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to match list items to items in dictionary value which are stored as a list.

I have the following list:

```
new_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
```

and the following dictionary:

```
new_dict = {abc: ['apple', 'kiwi'], bca: ['strawberry', 'banana', 'mango'], dcf: ['watermelon', 'apple', 'starfruit']}
```

What I want to do is match items in new_list to the items that are in the dictionary value list.

This is what my code looks like:

```
final_list = []
for k,v in new_dict.items():
    for values in v:
        for items in new_list:
            if items in values:
               print k
               print items
```

I believe the above code is computationally heavy. Also, when the above code does provide some results, it only matches the list items to the first index in the value list. For example, even though the list item "banana" is in the 2nd key:value pair, it doesn't match it. Is there a way to match every item in the value list?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue of "banana" not matching with your code. In any case, the best way to "fix" this code is probably going to be to reverse your dictionary. That is, switch it from `{"abc": ["apple", "kiwi"], "def": ["apple"]}` to `{"apple": ["abc", "def"], "kiwi": ["abc"]}`. Then your lookups can be very quick and efficient, as long as you only care about exact matches (rather than the substring matches you're currently doing).

Comment: None of the answers coming in seem to be addressing the issue you are really asking about, that "banana" doesn't get matched. The reason is that "banana" *does* get matched with the code you show. Can you find some data or update your example code to me a [mcve] so that we can actually investigate your main issue?

Comment: What desired output are you looking to get?

Comment: Sorry guys! Thanks for all the help. For some reason, it was only showing up the ones that matched to the 1st value list index. But the answers are correct

Answer (score 0):

You have one too many for loops.

`new_dict.items()` returns the keys and the values for said keys, so you dont need to iterate through `v`

```
for k, v in new_dict.items():
    for items in new_list:
        if items in v:
            print items, k
```

Output:

```
apple abc
banana bca
apple def
>>>
```

This isn't computationally heavy, you WILL need to iterate through `new_list` and you will need to check if an `item` in `new_list` is in `v`.

Optimisation wise, you might want to sort your values in the dictionary so that less comparisons are needed to check `if items in v` but I doubt you'll see any significant increase in speed. Best way would be to have a nice and efficient structure for whatever it is that you are doing.

That being said, I'm fairly new to optimisation so please it take with quite a large pinch of salt.

Also lastly:

`new_dict = {'abc': ['apple', 'kiwi'], 'bca': ['strawberry', 'banana', 'mango'], 'def': ['watermelon', 'apple', 'starfruit']}` (syntax)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I just typed up the sample for this question but I fixed the error. 
I had tried the code that you provided before but I keep running into the same problem, it matches just to the first item in the value list and stops if it doesn't find it there. The number of matches I am getting should be higher than what's resulting from this script.

Comment: I'm not sure the extra loop is a problem (though it may be unnecessary). It means that the `in` test is doing a substring match, which may be what the questioner wants. For instance, if `new_string` contained `"an"`, it would match both `"banana"` and `"mango"`.

Comment: @had01 what is your desired output?

Comment: @Blckknght didn't think of that, in hindesight a desired output would've been nice but I also didnt ask

Comment: "For example, even though the list item "banana" is in the 2nd key:value pair, it doesn't match it" ..it is matched?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `new_list` to a set for more efficient lookups:

```
new_set = set(new_list)
for k, v in new_dict.items():
    for item in v:
        if item in new_set:
            print(k, item)
```

so that given:

```
new_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
new_dict = {'abc': ['apple', 'kiwi'], 'bca': ['strawberry', 'banana', 'mango'], 'dcf': ['watermelon', 'apple', 'starfruit']}
```

this outputs:

```
abc apple
bca banana
dcf apple
```